# Object Follow Curve - Geometry Nodes - Blender 3.0.0

Tags: geometry-nodes

I can't find a way using Geometry Nodes to get an primitive to follow a curve. I feel like this probably should be possible and ideally simple. (I know how to do this using constraints outside of GN, but this is the kind of thing that GN should simplify)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with the *Sample Curve* node. This node inputs a curve and a position along the curve, then outputs the position and direction of the curve at that point.
[image]

You can then animate the *Factor* input to move the sphere along the curve. Geometry nodes doesn't yet have a node to give the current frame, but you can create a *Value* node and enter the text `#frame` in it to create a driver that will get the current frame.

Comment: How do you do this for a collection of curves? I haven't figured out yet how to set the position of one geometry on to a collection of curves. It works only for setting the position on one of the curves in the collection of curves. The sample curve node has a curve index input where you can pick which curve in the collection you want to place the geometry. Should that input take some kind of number range of curve indexes? How? I haven't figured out how to make the sample curve node take in multiple curve indexes so that maybe the geometry is placed on multiple curves.