# Geometry node instances along curve transform?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to move instances along curve in geometry node from start to end and so for.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227192/how-can-i-move-lots-of-objects-on-path-and-control-it-somehow/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245601/object-follow-curve-geometry-nodes-blender-3-0-0/245604#245604

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example.

**Sample point** is used to get position and normal at a specific point of the curve.

To rotate object along normal, you should convert normal to rotation using **Align Euler to Vector**

[image]

Then you animate **factor** of **Sample point**, you will have a movement from start to end of the curve

Comment: Great but how to do it with multiple objects I forgot to mention ???

Comment: It's similar, but you have to use **translate instances** and **rotate instances** instead of **transform**, because **transform** can move only a single object.