# Displace modifier for curves

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, displacement

Is there any way to displace the points of a curve like the displace modifier does with the vertex of a mesh?

Comment: can you provide more, like pictures, of what exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can use _Geometry Nodes_ to do that. If you take a _Noise Texture_ to modify the positions of the curve points you can achieve something similar. You could also use _Resample Curve_ there to give the curve a higher resolution for displacing. I'm sorry I have no time at the moment to flesh it out as a proper answer. Maybe someone else is quicker or I'll try it later ;)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to animate them? Or displace along a precise shape? If you simply need to displace you can activate the Proportional Editing and choose its Random option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution in *Geometry Nodes*: select your curve object which you want to displace, open the *Geometry Node Editor* and click *New*.

Add a *Noise Texture* node and a *Set Position* node. If you would now connect the *Color* output of the *Noise Texture* with the *Offset* input and let the curve run through this setup you would already have some kind of displacement on the curve.

For more control, you could first of all use a *Resample Curve* node before setting the position. This way you can choose how detailed the noise/displacement will be. Depending on if you want curves of different lengths to look similar in detail or different due to their length, you could either choose *Length* or *Count* for resampling.

The next thing is, since the average value of the noise is 0.5 in all directions, all points will be shifted away 0.5 in XYZ from the original curve, so with a *Vector Math* > *Subtract* node you subtract 0.5 from all three channels.

The next thing is, the displacement might be too extreme - or not extreme enough? To change this, you can either use a *Vector Math* > *Scale* node (as I did in my example) to uniformly increase or decrease the displacement on all axes. Another method would be to set the *Vector Math* node to *Multiply*. This way you can decide for each direction how strong the displacement should be.

**EDIT:** Now that it turned out the curve should be used with another object as target in a *Follow Path* constraint - the constraint will not evaluate the displaced curve (as of version 3.2.0 so far). To use it, you have to convert it into mesh and back to curve in the viewport menu, *Object* > *Convert* > *Mesh* and *Object* > *Convert* > *Curve*. In this case you will lose the capability to procedurally change the curve. A solution is making the object follow the curve inside the *Geometry Nodes* setup, it's explained in short in the answer here: [Object Follow Curve - Geometry Nodes - Blender 3.0.0](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245601/).

[image: curve displacement]

Comment: Hello @Gordon Brinkmann thank you so much! I did what you said but my butterfly is still flying straight, without follow the noisy curve https://i.imgur.com/lqt9Gg7.gif

Comment: @douglasfigueira That's why people are asking in comments for more information on what you want to achieve ;) My solution displaces the curve, but a _Geometry Nodes_ curve will not be evaluated by the _Follow Path_ constraint on the butterfly. So to use it you have to convert the curve to mesh (not in _Geometry Nodes_) in the viewport menu with _Object_ > _Convert_ > _Mesh_ and back to curve with _Object_ > _Convert_ > _Curve_. And when I tried that, it only worked after I selected the curve and switched to _Edit Mode_ and back. Of course it's not procedural anymore afterwards.

Comment: @douglasfigueira Not enough space here for complex answers. Of course you could make the object follow the curve in _Geometry Nodes_. The answer how to do that you can find in the question [Object Follow Curve - Geometry Nodes - Blender 3.0.0](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245601/). Instead of the Icosphere there you have to bring in your butterfly with the _Object Info_ node.

Comment: Thank you again @Gordon I'll try it later.